# How do assert one list in another list with same order

Tags: java, assert, assertions, hamcrest

I have one list which contains recent 5 dates of order

```
List<String> recentFiveOrdersDates = new ArrayList<>();
```

values in list are :

```
["20/07/2018", "19/07/2018", "18/07/2018", "18/07/2018", "18/07/2018"]
```

I have another list which contains all dates of order:

```
List<String> AllOrderDates = new ArrayList<>();
```

And values in this list are  :

```
["20/07/2018", "19/07/2018", "18/07/2018", "18/07/2018", "18/07/2018", "17/07/2018", "17/07/2018", "16/07/2018", "16/07/2018", "12/07/2018", "12/07/2018", "17/05/2018"]
```

Now I want to assert the recent five order list in the all orders list. Is it possible to verify they're in the same order?

I have used `assertThat()` method of **hamcrest** but I'm not sure it work in same way

```
assertThat(AllOrderDates, contains(recentFiveOrdersDates.toArray()));
```

Comment: Maybe test the equality with a `AllOrderDates.subList(0, recentFiveOrdersDates.size())` or something like that?

Comment: @ Arnaud Denoyelle, This could be the way but while I'm using in assertion it giving the exception. any idea how to fit this one in assert ?

Answer (score 5):

The [`contains(T... items)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains(E...)) method cater to the ordering already.

If you do **not** want ordering you may use [`containsInAnyOrder(T... items)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(T...)).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. but you know while i do assert sub-list in main list it showing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError`. Is it so we have to assert equal size list  ?